# Is there a reference for the 'normal' glm operators?

Tags: c++, glm-math

I use the glm library for a project, but I run into errors all the time. Not because of the documented functions like `glm::length(...)` or something like that, but because of the overload of normal operators.

At the moment f. ex. I only try to multiply a vector with a float `glm::dvec2 f = (1, 0); glm::dvec2 g = f * 0.5f;` But I get an error because of the used `invalid operands to binary expression` of the dvec2 and the float.

So is there anywere a documentation of how the 'normal' math operators or their overloads in glm behave and what is allowed/possible and what is not?

Comment: You can try to look at the GLSL specification. glm types should behave like types from GLSL.

Comment: Thanks, that is a good idea. I found that normally this operation should be possible, but it is the combination of the `float f` with the `dvec2` which caused the error in the mentioned case. With `double f` it works fine.